# Fail to add .png to page in a OJet project

Tags: html, oracle-jet

I am working on Jet and now have to insert a image in the page. It should be very easy but now I am just not able to make this image shown in the page.

To ensure that there is no path error, I put the image and the html file in the same folder: src/js/views.

Below is the html code snippet:

```
<img src="xxx.png" style="width:89.25pt;height:18.75pt;" alt="xxx logo">
```

But the page just shows a broken icon but not this image.

Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Go to your browser's Dev Tools -> Network, and search for your image's request to server (If you cannot find it reload the page while keeping the Dev Tools open.) Does the URL path to the image look correct to you? If not, correct it.
2. If it still isn't working try using `<image>` tag instead. This worked for me.